# Opportunity Validation Rule on Primary Campaign

Tags: formula, opportunity, validation, lookup, validation-rule

I must be going crazy.  On an Opportunity I want the Validation Rule to trigger when no Primary Campaign has been selected.  This is a Standard Field on the Opportunity so the rule I set up is

ISNULL(Campaign.Id)

but I can still edit and save Opportunities that don't have any Campaign selected.  I can't figure out what I am missing.  The Standard Field is as such

`Label                        Name           DataType
Primary Campaign Source     Campaign    Lookup(Campaign)`

Comment: this is covered here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008wgKIAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the ISNULL function, you should use the ISBLANK() function. It is better to use it for text fields (lookup is considered as a text field).

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISBLANK